# Bootstrap 4 modal backdrop not dismissing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue with BS4 modals not dismissing the modal-backdrop class when the modal is closed. Not sure what is going on here, modals are usually pretty straight forward! Here is my code:

```
<header>

    <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#menu">
                <span class="fa fa-bars"> Menu</span>
            </button>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="menu" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <nav class="nav flex-column">
                        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Weird. I just made [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stinnett_casey/m5q9rd6f/) with your exact code and it works. When I click on the modal backdrop, it all disappears. I did make sure to add jQuery first, then the bootstrap js and css. The order is important.

```
<ul class="nav pull-right">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#menu">
            <span class="fa fa-bars"> Menu</span>
        </button>
    </li>
</ul>

<div id="menu" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                </button>
                <nav class="nav flex-column">
                    <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Active</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have the css loaded in the <head> and jquery and the bootstrap.js at the end of the document. will this effect things?

Comment: turns out the issue was a conflict in the CMS I am using. They have the bootstrap js for v3 embedded into a lib.min.js file and I was double loading bootstraps JS. I removed it from the lib file and all is good in the wold now.

Comment: Good to hear, Sandra.